# Not start mysql in xampp 7.4

Tags: php

I have a problem with xampp.. I tried many things but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: The error messages mean that you already installed MySQL server separately and it's running and occupied port 3306. Close it and then restart xampp's mysql.

Comment: Change port of mysql service.

Comment: Go to the MySQL path C->program files->MySQL->MySQL Server 5.1->bin and check if any of mysql stop file available there and stop mysql running from it. Also you can check the services and stop if any other MySQL service running on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You have already installed MySQL server. You have the mysql server started already and it occupies the 3306 port, so xampp cant use it.

Try:

- Stopping the mysql server located at C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\
- Uninstall the MySQL server if its not needed
- Change port of the MySQL server